# How many wives did Hazrat Hassan (R.A) had?

Tags: history, sahaba

I have heard rumors that Hassan (RA),grand child of the prophet, had over 100 wives (4 at a time though). I found [this reference](http://www.al-islam.org/al-serat/imamhasan.htm) which talks about this claim too

> Some have reported 70 wives. Others have increased the number to 90.
>   Still others have said 250 wives! The highest number is 300! (excerpt from above link)

**Is there any truth to it? If not what is exact number of wives he had and what were their names?**

Comment: After a quick research, it's somehow hard to give a clear answer to this question, there is big confusion about these stories, Historians record some of them, but most Hadith scholars say they're not authentic.

Comment: your link is not a reference for this claim. this link mentioned 70 wives as a Myth fabricated to defame him. not as a fact. have you ever read your own reference link?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of his wives is not recorded in history, and Shia scholars do not speculate about this number. At least the scholars I asked said this is not recorded in history.

But in different books, the names of a maximum of 13 women are mentioned as his wives (not necessarily all authentic).  They are also not mentioned as his wives at the same time.

I think your own link is best answer to this question.

If he had lots of wives, he should have lots of children also, but the number of his children were 15 according to researches of [Al-Shaykh Al-Mufid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shaykh_Al-Mufid). Some references mentioned up to 25 children.

It does not seem logical that he would have 100 wives and only 15 or 25 children.

Also, a fabricated Hadith says that he divorced his wives, who then participated in his funeral. How is this logical? Usually a divorced woman, especially one divorced from someone who has many wives, would never participate in the funeral of her ex-husband.

He was a very pious and respected man.  Such accusations do not match with his personality as recorded in history. Please study what happened to his body when he died and with whom.

I think if you read your own link carefully, you will find the answer.

**Reference:**

[www.makarem.ir](http://makarem.ir/websites/farsi/maaref/?qid=3065&gro=3716&sw=)

[www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/al-serat/imamhasan.htm)